# Update Azure keyvault secret through Azure API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-keyvault

I am trying to update keyvault secret in Azure through Postman. But getting Authorization error.
Any suggestions. Anything I am missing. Thanks in advance

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "AKV10022: Invalid audience. Expected https://vault.azure.net, found: https://management.azure.com/."
  }
}
```

Using the below to update the secret:

```
PUT https://demokv.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretname?api-version=7.0
```

in Body:

```
{
  "value": "mysecretvalue"
}
```

Comment: seems that the problem is related to the way you're acquiring the authorization token (passed in the Authorization header).

Comment: Worked fine after adding audience for keyvault. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in another  reply, the `audience` of your token is not correct, to call Azure Keyvault REST API - [`Set Secret - Set Secret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/setsecret/setsecret), the `audience` should be `https://vault.azure.net`.

To get the token, you could use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) in the postman.

1.[Register an AD App in azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application), then [get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret).

2.Navigate to the keyvault in the portal, [add the service principal of the AD App to the Access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#configure-access-policies-on-resources).

In the postman, follow the screenshot below, fix the properties that got from step 1.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=<client_id>
&scope=https://vault.azure.net/.default
&client_secret=<client_secret>
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

[image]

Then copy the token to call the REST API to set secret, it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: can you pls link to where the api scopes(https://vault.azure.net) for keyvault and other resources are documented?

Answer (score 8):

Also, you can get the token with `az account get-access-token --resource "https://vault.azure.net"`

To specificity vault resource

Comment: Was looking for a human way to do it all day! It work from both TFS (Windows) and Cloud CLI. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You acquired the access token (Bearer) for the wrong audience,

```
AKV10022: Invalid audience.
Expected https://vault.azure.net,
Found: https://management.azure.com/.
```

Acquire a new one for the correct audience and give it another go.

Comment: Worked fine after adding audience for keyvault. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My challenge was using the older version of the oauth API.

Ensure that you're using:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

And not:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
```